# How can I migrate from IBM BladeCenter chassis E to chassis H?

Tags: ibm, bladecenter

I'm planning to migrate blade server HS22 and all modules (2 ESMs, 2Brocade SAN Switch modules) from chassis E to chassis H. Do I need to reconfigure all modules? And how about servers? Please share any exp.
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is call the company and check with them. They would be a lot more knowledgeable about their products then some joe from a Tech site. I'm sure they have a help desk dedicated to questions just like this.

Comment: Got a call with IBM staff, and they said that I only to plug out all modules, plug them in new chassis in exactly the same order. I followed, and it worked.